# SQLITE Custom DataTypes?

Tags: sql, types, sqlite

I am fairly new to SQLITE and I noticed that there are only a 4 datatypes but I see examples online where people are putting in their own datatypes.  I don't really understand this and was wondering if someone could explain that to me.  For example I see a column that will hold a date and the datatype that was given was timestamp which does not exist.  What does it default to? Does it default to a text when you make your own?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`sqlite3` uses a dynamic type system. There are only five storage classes:
NULL, integer, real, text and blob. (Source: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).)

And, to quote that page:

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

Apart from the `integer primary key` exception, SQLite doesn't enforce types at all. Which means that the type name you put in your `create table` is purely informative.

```
create table mytab (a apples, b bananas);
```

is a valid `create table` statement. You can insert timestamps, text, blobs into both columns (not saying that you *should*, but you can).

Look at the linked reference documentation for the type system for more information.

```
sqlite> create table mytab (a apples, b bananas);
sqlite> insert into mytab values (CURRENT_TIME, NULL);
sqlite> insert into mytab values ('hello', 3.14159);
sqlite> select * from mytab;
14:59:18|
hello|3.14159
```

To answer your question directly: there is no default. A storage type is associated with each value stored in the database, not to columns of a table.

Comment: Note that this was last updated in 2011, and since then sqlite has a STRICT option for tables. Still no custom types though.

https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html