# Same SQL code works in one site without problem - but not at the other site

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

https://sqliteonline.com/

```
CREATE TABLE dept1 
(
    deptno number,
    dname varchar(14),
    loc varchar(14),
    create_date date default_sysdate
);
```

Works perfectly.

Copy/paste code at https://livesql.oracle.com/

and then I get this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I get the same error at https://apex.oracle.com

Code is really simple :-/ Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need `default sysdate`, not `default_sysdate`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51c8d43e916503e2cd8ed2c45d2b2b97)

Comment: Many workplaces block links. Many of of refuse to open them for the same reason others block them.  You should paste your code directly into your question.

Comment: So the two sites are using completely different RDBMS products? That seems a bit "this PS4 game doesn't play on my Xbox".

Answer (score 3):

When you run the code on [sqliteonline](https://sqliteonline.com/), you're creating a table in SQLite. There's no `sysdate` in SQLite instead you've to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

SQLite doesn't enforce type names. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417411/2427065) for details.

So in your case, SQLite consider `date default_sysdate` as the column type.

You can verify it by running `pragma table_info(dept1)`. A screenshot is attached below.

[image]

In the second link, you're running Oracle database not SQLite. It does have strict types and that's why you're getting error.

Comment: Aha. So that's why it worked on SQLite. Kind of "stupid" :), Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely doubt your words. "Works perfect" is not likely to happen because there's no `default_sysdate` - should be two separated words.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE dept1 ( deptno number, dname varchar(14), loc varchar(14), create_date date default_sysdate );
CREATE TABLE dept1 ( deptno number, dname varchar(14), loc varchar(14), create_date date default_sysdate )
                                                                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> CREATE TABLE dept1 ( deptno number, dname varchar(14), loc varchar(14), create_date date default sysdate );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Besides, use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`.

Comment: OP is running the code in sqlite in first link. SQLite doesn't throw error instead consider `date default_sysdate` as data type. The rest of your answer is valid for why OP is getting the error on oracle.